# Sample corr vs population correlation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wanna ask that the function `corr()` in pandas
normally, when we use "corr()"
like `x.corr(y)` is finding the correlation between x and y 
so is it population correlation? 
how if I wanna find sample correlation?

can anyone give me some example???

Thanks a lot

So how if i wanna calculate population correlation?

Comment: This is obviously the sample correlation. How would this function know what the population means are?

Comment: So how if i wanna calculate population correlation?